# How to find the location of a python package installed via egg-link?

Tags: python, setuptools, pip

I'm working on a plugin architecture and need to convert a package name like "foo.bar" to the absolute path where the code resides. imp.find_module seems to do what I want, except when the code in question is installed via an egg-link (installed via 'pip install develop').

If there are two modules foo.bar and foo.bar2 which are installed via egg-links (and which live at completely separate file system locations like /home/bob/foo/bar and /home/alice/foo/bar2), find_modules doesn't work because I look up the package "foo" and get the location to foo/bar, but not foo/bar2.

Anyone have suggestions for an alternative function? find_modules doesn't accept hierarchical names, so I can't just pass "foo.bar2" into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just import the module and inspect its `__file__` attribute:

```
import os
import foo.bar

print(os.path.abspath(foo.bar.__file__))
```

For dynamic imports:

```
import os
import sys

module_name = 'foo.bar'
__import__(module_name)
print(os.path.abspath(sys.modules[module_name].__file__))
```

Comment: Since these are plugins, I don't know the package names in advance, and therefore can't use import. I need to take a string like "foo.bar" and convert it to a package location.

Comment: @cberner: You can use dynamic imports with `__import__`, see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: If you don't know the package names, how can you use find_module either?  (For that matter, why not just use entry points for your plugin system?)

Comment: @pjeby: He does not know the package name *in advance*.  At runtime, he has the name as a string ("foo.bar" in his example).

Comment: Ah yes, that works great. Didn't realize `__import__` existed. Thanks!